# Registering email SMTP setting and using them in Code

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I've added into my web.config file the following settings for my smtp:

```
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="noreply@***.com">
      <network host="mail.***.com"
               port="***"
               userName="noreply@***.com    "
               password="***."
               enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
```

I'm trying now to register this in the config section like I did the previous packages, for example:

```
<configSection>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

  </configSections>
```

And then using the settings from web config in my code like:

```
   public static async void ResetPasswordEmail(string emailTo)
        {
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo)); //replace with valid value
            message.Subject = "Your email subject";
            message.Body = "This is test Email";
            message.IsBodyHtml = false;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
              await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            }
        }
```

How can I register the mail settings in config section of the web config and then use it in my code ??

Comment: You don't need to create a custom section. You can use built in configuration schema to specify these settings, [see the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code :-

```
 using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
                {
                    // Get modified content from the template.Its optional if you don't want to populate body
                    var body = PopulateBody(replaceParameters, emailTemplate);

                    // Setup the mail configuration.
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(Utils.Setting.UserName, Utils.Setting.SenderDisplayName);
                    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                    mailMessage.Body = body;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to, recepientName));    
                    if (mailMessage.To != null && mailMessage.To.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Initiat smtp configuration.
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                        smtp.Host = Host;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(Utils.Setting.EnableSsl);
                        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                        // Pass the sender credentials.
                        NetworkCred.UserName = UserName;
                        NetworkCred.Password = Password;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                        smtp.Port = int.Parse(Port);

                        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                    }
                }
```

You can add settings in web.config file as below :-

```
 <appSettings>
 <add key="Host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="EnableSsl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Ans can access it like :-

```
string Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
```

Comment: Please mark as answer, if it works for you, so it can help other person too.

Comment: Why would you promote custom appSettings over using the built in configuration schema for `mailSettings`?